# How to show a link in the text of HTML.TextAreaFor in MVC Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a form with a HTML. TextArea For which user can insert text in it ( like news ). I want to allow user to have text contains link. I can add `[AllowHtml]` to the property of this field, but I don't know how to have link in the text and then when I save it into my database, how to show it when I am reading it from website. Is there any solution ?
my program is written in `Visual Studio 2013, C# .Net 4.0, MVC 4.0 Razor`

---- UPDATED ----

Thanks for your comments

let me explain more - I am writing an application for a community. In part of my application ( or website ) I want to show news of the community to the users. For inserting these news I have an Admin controller which admin can create a new news for the website and I have a model for new news. This model has a property for NewsText. In the view of CreateNews, admin can insert text of the news into TextArea and I am showing it by @Html.TextAreaFor(...). So after inserting Text here and pressing Save button, model will go to controller for saving into database. First problem is here, imagine that in part of news there is a link, how can admin enter this link ? in the form of 'a' tag or something else ?
Then when website wants to show that news to the end user, controller gets NewsText from database and wants to show it on the screen. Now, how can I show the link ? Razor will parse it automatically or I have to do it something else ?

Comment: You want to display the link as a real hyperlink *in the text box?*

Comment: When displaying the text (including the anchor) use the razor `@Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.YourTextProperty)`

Comment: I have added some more details, please see the question again

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you actually want to use a WYSIWYG editor, since you mention the ability for the user to add a link to the text: [List of WYSIWYG HTML editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_editor#WYSIWYG_HTML_editors)

You then save and show via `@Html.Raw()` as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to save the text as is to the DB.
When reading the text from the DB use regex to look for any links.
replace the text with the same text only warped in "a" tag. 
This can be also done upon insertion to the DB.

Comment: I have added some more details, please see the question again

Answer (score 0):

Let user add html as you are doing now.
while showing
Try @Html.Raw(Text)

Comment: I have added some more details, please see the question again